# Java generics, nested collection of wildcard

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

This compiles (1.6)

```
List<? extends Object> l = new ArrayList<Date>();
```

But this does not

```
List<List<? extends Object>> ll = new ArrayList<List<Date>>();
```

with the error of

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from ArrayList<List<Date>> to List<List<? extends Object>>
```

Could someone explain why?
Thanks

EDIT: edited for being consequent

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Because it would break type safety:

```
List<List<Object>> lo = new ArrayList<List<Object>>();
List<List<? extends Object>> ll = lo;
List<String> ls = new ArrayList<String>();
ll.add(ls);
lo.get(0).add(new Object());
String s = ls.get(0); // assigns a plain Object instance to a String reference
```

Comment: People may want to read up on C#'s covariant/contravariant declarations for generic interfaces and delegates which was added in 4.0. That is one way to "solve" this problem (well it changes the problem first)

Comment: @Voo see a very old paper "On Variance-Based Subtyping for Parametric Types". the two approaches were analyzed for their pros/cons. Java went one way, C# went another way, but there is nothing new. C#'s approach appears simple in simple case, but the complexity easily becomes unmanageable, as the paper stated. (I don't appreciate C# people present it as something they invented and magical without flaw)

Comment: @irreputable Will look at the paper if I have time for some surely highly non trivial talk about co/contravariance ;) And well Generics are complicated to begin with but being able to express co/contravariance can be useful sometimes. But sure nothing for the faint-hearted. But then Java didn't have a choice to begin with - I don't see how that could be implemented backwards compatible. But then I think everybody agrees that Java's implementation is horrible as is, so really no good idea to add anything on top of it

Comment: lo.get(0).add(new Object()); would raise an error, since you try to add an object to a list of string.

Comment: @Voo Scala also does it that way.

Answer (score 24):

Well the explanations are correct, but I think it'd be a nice thing to add the actual working solution as well ;)

```
List<? extends List<? extends Object>>
```

Will work just fine, but obviously the use of such a collection is quite limited by the usual limitations of generic Collections (but then the same is true for the simpler List< ? extends Date >)

Answer (score 3):

Suppose `D` is subtype of `B`, `G<T>` is a generic type

```
B x = new D(); // OK

G<B> y = new G<D>(); // FAIL
```

Now, `G<Date>` is a subtype of `G<?>`, therefore

```
G<?> x = new G<Date>();  // OK

G<G<?>> y = new G<G<Date>>(); // FAIL
```

Answer (score 2):

When assigning to a variable (`List<T>`) with a non-wildcard generic type `T`, the object being assigned must have exactly `T` as its generic type (including all generic type parameters of `T`, wildcard and non-wildcard). In your case `T` is `List<? extends Object>`, which is not the same type as `List<Date>`.

What you can do, because `List<Date>` is assignable to `List<? extends Object>`, is use the wildcard type:

```
List<? extends List<? extends Object>> a = new ArrayList<List<Date>>();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<? extends Object>
```

means that the wildcard could be substituted only for those objects, that are subclass of `Object` class.

```
List<List<? extends Object>> ll = new ArrayList<List<Object>>();
```

gives you error of type mismatch because you are trying to assign a `ArrayList` of List of object of java class `Object` to a `List` that contains the `List` of any type of objects that are subclass of java class `Object`.

For more ref, have a look at the [Wildcard documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html)