# Using wildcard with Lists.partition and nested generic types

Tags: java, generics

I am using [Lists.partition](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#partition%28java.util.List,%20int%29) from [Google Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/), although I have a feeling this is a general question about generics in Java.

I can do this:

```
public void doSomething(List<DataBean> ids) {
    List<List<DataBean>> lists = Lists.partition(ids, MAX_ITEMS);
```

Why can't I do this?

```
public void doSomething(List<? extends DataBean> ids) {
    List<List<? extends DataBean>> lists = Lists.partition(ids, MAX_ITEMS);
```

I get the following complilation error:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<List<capture#1-of ? extends DataBean>> to List<List<? extends DataBean>>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to bind the type so that it matches throughout. Otherwise, the `?` for `lists` is not related to the `?` for `ids`. You can declare a generic method with a named type parameter, rather than a generic parameter with a wildcard:

```
public <T extends DataBean> void doSomething(List<T> ids) {
    List<List<T>> lists = lists.partition(ids, MAX_ITEMS);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The `partition` method is declared as such

```
public static <T> List<List<T>> partition(List<T> list, int size)
```

Because of the declaration of the generic type variable `T`, the method becomes generic and the type variable captures the type argument used. You use `? extends DataBean` as a type argument, so that is said to be captured in `T`.

So now `T` is really `cap#1 of ? extends DataBean`. And the method is set to return that. In other words, to your invocation, it would look like

```
public static List<List<cap#1 of ? extends DataBean>> partition(List<cap#1 of ? extends DataBean> list, int size) {
```

The capture can be any type that extends `DataBean`. Let's assume it's some type called `SubBean`. The method would, conceptually (in truth, the capture is the true type), return a

```
List<List<SubBean>>
```

But you are trying to assign its return value to a variable of type

```
List<List<? extends DataBean>>
```

But because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6293871/java-generics-nested-collection-of-wildcard), ie. that nested generic types don't play well together, you cannot assign `List<List<SubBean>>` to `List<List<? extends DataBean>>`.

As a solution that the previous link suggests, you could change your declaration to

```
public void doSomething(List<? extends DataBean> ids) {
    List<? extends List<? extends DataBean>> lists = partition(ids, 3);
}
```

But I would suggest not using wildcards when there are [solutions like Ted's.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21838410/438154)