# Java Generics Cast to Wildcard Rules

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

In the simple case, I can easily downgrade from a generic type to a wildcard type:

```
List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<>();
List<?> wildList = intList; // I can cast to a List<?>
```

However, as my generics get more complicated:

```
List<List<Integer>> nestedIntList = new ArrayList<>();
List<List<?>> nestedWildList = nestIntList; // This does not compile
```

Is there a way that this can be made to compile?  Am I missing some logical case that the compiler is protecting me from? Why can I not cast the inner type?

Answer (score 1):

`List<Integer>` is assignable to `List<?>` or `List<? extends Integer>`. Similarly you can assign it to a `List<? extends Number>` but **not** to `List<Number>`.

On similar lines, you can only assign `List<List<Integer>>` to `List<? extends List<?>>`

See:

[`Is List<Dog> a subclass of List<Animal>? Why are Java generics not implicitly polymorphic?`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-are-java-generics-not-implicitly-po)

[Java generics, nested collection of wildcard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6293871/java-generics-nested-collection-of-wildcard)