# Java capture and incompatible types

Tags: java, generics

I have the following code:

```java
Collection<Something<ConcreteA, ConcreteB>> methodOne() {
   ....
}

void methodTwo(Collection<Something<ConcreteA, ?>> val) {
   ....
}
 
// This call generates an error.
methodTwo(methodOne());
```

The `methodTwo(methodOne())` generates an error: `incompatible types: Collection<Something<ConcreteA,ConcreteB>> cannot be converted to Collection<Something<ConcreteA,?>>`.

I understand that I can just cast `methodTwo((Collection) methodOne())` and everything works fine except for the `Unchecked assignment` warning which can be ignored. But that defeats the purpose of using generics. Changing `methodTwo` signature from capture to Object also does not help, i.e. `methodTwo(Collection<Something<ConcreteA, Object>> val)` also produces a similar error.

What am I doing wrong? What is the right way of dealing with it?

Comment: Method two is not declared as a generic method; you haven't declared any generic type parameters for the method.

Comment: What you're probably looking for is something along the lines of `void methodTwo <K>(Collection<Something<ConcreteA, K>> val)`, although I'm not sure this kind of type parameterization works; you'll have to try it.

Comment: Yes, indeed. Thanks. If you make it into an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: THe problem I had is that <K> is not used at all by `methodTwo`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6293871/java-generics-nested-collection-of-wildcard) for details on using wildcard in nested types.

In short, what you're trying to do is not type safe with wildcard. And it doesn't work, because in Java generics (e.g. `Collection<T>`) [are invariant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8482091/1349366).

To quote @irreputable's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6294260/1349366) (modified):

> Suppose `D` is subtype of `B`:
>
> ```
> B x = new D(); // OK
>
> Collection<B> y = new ArrayList<B>(); // OK
> ArrayList<B> y = new ArrayList<D>(); // FAIL
> ```
>
> Now, `Something<ConcreteA, ConcreteB>` is a subtype of `Something<ConcreteA, ?>`, therefore
>
> ```
> Something<ConcreteA, ?> x = new Something<ConcreteA, ConcreteB>();  // OK
>
> ArrayList<Something<ConcreteA, ?>> y = 
>    new ArrayList<Something<ConcreteA, ConcreteB>>(); // FAIL
> ```

---

The solution in your case would be to make `methodTwo` generic, as @RobertHarvey suggested:

```
void methodTwo <K>(Collection<Something<ConcreteA, K>> val)
```

This way `Something<ConcreteA, K>` type is fixed to type you're actually passing (as opposed to being its subtype), and the type safety is guaranteed.

Answer (score 1):

Generics are invariant. Unless the top level type argument is wildcard, the type arguments must be identical.

`Collection<Something<ConcreteA, ConcreteB>>` is NOT a subtype of `Collection<Something<ConcreteA, ?>>`, even though `Something<ConcreteA, ConcreteB>` is a subtype of `Something<ConcreteA, ?>`, for the same reason that `Collection<String>` is not a subtype of `Collection<Object>` even though `String` is a subtype of `Object`.

If you want to accept potentially different type parameters, you can put a wildcard in the top level, like this:

```
void methodTwo(Collection<? extends Something<ConcreteA, ?>> val) { }
```