# Type of array based on parameter in Java

Tags: java, generics

I have a byte array like this, that I do some operations on like increment and decrement.

```
byte[] cells = new byte[numCells]
....
....
cells[index]++;
```

Now, I want to change the type of the array cells based on some user input parameter to byte, short, int or long.

So, I made a new class Cell

```
public class Cell<T extends Number> {

    T cell;

    Cell(T defaultValue){

        cell = defaultValue;
    }

    T get(){
        return cell;
    }

    void set(T t){
        cell = t;
    }
}
```

And I am trying to use it like this

```
ArrayList<Cell<?>> cells;

if(cellSize == 8)
    cells = new ArrayList<Cell<Byte>>(numCells);
else if(cellSize == 16)
    cells = new ArrayList<Cell<Short>>(numCells);
...
...
```

The compiler throws the following error

```
error: incompatible types: ArrayList<Cell<Byte>> cannot be converted to ArrayList<Cell<?>>
cells = new ArrayList<Cell<Byte>>(numCells);
        ^
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: note that using a parameter to decide at runtime what array to instantiate, makes the generics here a bit useless... I wonder if the parameter itself (8, 16, 32, etc) can be used to instantiate the correct array without an "if" statement...   if there is no way, I would try a factory pattern based on a map where the key is your type size (8, 16, etc) and the value is the type of the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd have to type the variable as [`ArrayList<? extends Cell<?>>`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6293871/2541560).

But even if that gets it to compile, it might not help you much. Wildcards are useful as method parameters, otherwise they're mostly a hindrance.

You might want to redesign your code so that the class is used in another class which has a type variable shared with `Cell<T>`, such as `Table<T>` so you just work with `T` inside both classes, and use the actual type in your "main" code when instantiating a `Table<Short>` for example.

Comment: But I would then have the same problem with Table class right?

Comment: @SandeepTadepalli only if your Table can contain different kinds of cells. If that's the case you'll have to rethink your design since generics won't help you no matter what.

Answer (score 0):

You have to obey the covariance/contravariance rules of the language.

```
ArrayList<Cell<Byte>>
// is not assignable to
ArrayList<Cell<?>>
```

but:

```
ArrayList<Cell<Byte>>
// is not assignable to
ArrayList<? extends Cell<?>>
```

Comment: Well having said that. add()-ing and get()-ing from this type isn't possible without casting it back to something without a wildcard ... But thats correct, since you specified that the element of the array is at least Cell<?> but you dont' know the actual type. so you cannot just add a new Cell<Byte>()

Comment: I would explain it this way: when instantiating an array with a specific type, i.e.  new Array<Cell<Byte>>(), we allow to add only Cell<Byte> elements. Hence, we don't allow to add Cell<Short> elements or any other types.  But Array<Cell<?>> is "broader" and may accept other types than Cell<Byte> elements.  That's why it is not possible.

Comment: Since you're trying to instantiate different types of arrays, I would in this case use a "raw" list type which can accept any type of list.   simply use:  List myList;   without any generics.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to decide for your generics on creation time:

```java
List<Cell<?>> cells = new ArrayList<>(10);

cells.add(new Cell(Short.MAX_VALUE));
cells.add(new Cell(Byte.MAX_VALUE));
```

Comment: This will work, but I cannot guarantee that all of the Cell objects in the list will be of a single type right?